# syntax error near unexpected token `<' for shell script block in Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, jenkins-groovy

I have the below block of shell script code in Jenkinsfile

```
stage("Compose Source Structure")
    {   
        sh '''
            set -x
            rm -vf config
            wget -nv --no-check-certificate https://test-company/k8sconfigs/test-config
            export KUBECONFIG=$(pwd)/test-config
            kubectl config view
            ns_exists=$(kubectl get namespaces | grep ${consider_namespace})
            echo "Validating k8s namespace"
            if [ -z "$ns_exists" ]
            then
                echo "No namespace ${consider_namespace} exists in the cluster ${source_cluster}"
                exit 1                          
            else
                echo "scanning namespace \'${namespace}\'"
                mkdir -p "${HOME}/cluster-backup/${namespace}"
                while read -r resource
                do
                    echo "scanning resource \'${resource}\'"
                    mkdir -p "${HOME}/sync-cluster/${namespace}/${resource}"
                    while read -r item
                    do
                        echo "exporting item \'${item}\'"
                        kubectl get "$resource" -n "$namespace" "$item" -o yaml > "${HOME}/sync-cluster/${namespace}/${resource}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-${source_cluster}-${consider_namespace}-$item.yaml"
                    done < <(kubectl get "$resource" -n "$namespace" 2>&1 | tail -n +2 | awk \'{print $1}\')
                done < <(kubectl api-resources --namespaced=true 2>/dev/null | tail -n +2 | awk \'{print $1}\')
            fi
        '''
```

Unfortunately, I am getting error like below:

```
++ kubectl get namespaces
++ grep test
+ ns_exists='test              Active   2d20h'
+ echo 'Validating k8s namespace'
Validating k8s namespace
/home/jenkins/workspace/k8s-sync-from-cluster@tmp/durable-852103cd/script.sh: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

I did try to escape "<" with "", so I did like the below

```
\<
```

But still having no success, any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Basic POSIX `sh` doesn't understand `<(command)` process substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs for the `sh` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) (emphasis mine):

> Runs a Bourne shell script, typically on a Unix node. Multiple lines are accepted.
> An interpreter selector may be used, for example: `#!/usr/bin/perl`
> Otherwise the **system default shell** will be run, using the `-xe` flags (you can specify `set +e` and/or `set +x` to disable those).

The system default shell on your Jenkins server may be `sh`, not bash. POSIX `sh` will not recognize `<(command)` process substitution.

To specifically use the bash shell, you must include a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang immediately after your triple quote. Putting a shebang on the next line will have no effect.

I also took the liberty of fixing [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) warnings for your shell code, and removing `\'` escapes that are not necessary.

Try this:

```
stage("Compose Source Structure")
{   
    sh '''#!/usr/bin/env bash
    set -x
    rm -vf config
    wget -nv --no-check-certificate https://test-company/k8sconfigs/test-config
    KUBECONFIG="$(pwd)/test-config"
    export KUBECONFIG
    kubectl config view
    ns_exists="$(kubectl get namespaces | grep "${consider_namespace}")"
    echo "Validating k8s namespace"
    if [ -z "$ns_exists" ]
    then
        echo "No namespace ${consider_namespace} exists in the cluster ${source_cluster}"
        exit 1                          
    else
        echo "scanning namespace '${namespace}'"
        mkdir -p "${HOME}/cluster-backup/${namespace}"
        while read -r resource
        do
            echo "scanning resource '${resource}'"
            mkdir -p "${HOME}/sync-cluster/${namespace}/${resource}"
            while read -r item
            do
                echo "exporting item '${item}'"
                kubectl get "$resource" -n "$namespace" "$item" -o yaml > "${HOME}/sync-cluster/${namespace}/${resource}/${BUILD_NUMBER}-${source_cluster}-${consider_namespace}-$item.yaml"
            done < <(kubectl get "$resource" -n "$namespace" 2>&1 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}')
        done < <(kubectl api-resources --namespaced=true 2>/dev/null | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}')
    fi
    '''
}
```

Comment: Beautiful!, works like a charm! Together we grow :)